# What does Eru Ilúvatar's name mean?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, names, tolkien-languages, iluvatar

So I was wondering whether Eru Ilúvatar has any meaning in and of itself, in-universe, besides being the name of the Creator? Is it at all related to any words in Primitive Quendian, for example?

Out-of-universe, did Tolkien derive the name from anything? Or did he just make it up?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132164/whats-the-difference-between-the-names-eru-illuvatar

Comment: Out of universe: Tolkien may have been inspired by the name of Ilmatar, a creator goddess in the Kalevala (Finnish national epic with at least some influence on his works, according to Google).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Eru Ilúvatar means the “All Father”

> Eru 'The One', 'He that is Alone'
>
> Ilúvatar 'Father of All’
> <sub>The Silmarillion, Index of Names</sub>

The name Ilúvatar is a compound of two words, Ilu/Ilúvë ("the all", "everything, the world") and atar ("father"). The name has existed in the legendarium as early as the *Book of Lost Tales*. In Qenya (note the spelling) it meant "Sky-father".

*"Ilu"* in the early legendarium was used to describe the universe and everything in it. Coming from the root IL, meaning "all".
*"Atar"* comes from the root ATA meaning "father".
So there is to some extent a relation to Primitive Quendian and Qenya as the roots of the composition of the name Ilúvatar.

Éru (and particularly the spelling with the acute accent) came into the Legendarium later, at a similar time to the formation of Adunaic and the origins of the Akallabêth (*Sauron Defeated*). The use of the word in Quendian first appeared in a List of Names in 1951 (*Morgoth's Ring*).

Comment: Worth noting that "[atta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/#Gothic)" is the most commonly attested Gothic term for "father" as well. (Though Gothic isn't typically a source for Quenya vocabulary.)

Comment: I prefer to stick to sources I get directly from the works published during his lifetime or posthumously (edited by Christopher), but that is certainly interesting to note in the comments, and not something I'd known before.

Comment: All similarity to the Germanic words for "all+father", which is a common epithet for Odin (`Alfaðir` in the original Old Norse), is completely incidental :). For one thing, it partitions as `Iluv`+`atar`, not `Ilu`+`vatar`.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev That doesn’t mean it’s incidental, or indeed accidental. Having _Ilúvatar_ mean ‘Sky-Father’ and at the same time be so fairly close to Lat. _Iuppiter_, Gk. _Ζεῦ Πατέρ_, Skt. द्यौष्पितृ (which also mean ‘Sky-Father’) does not make them cognates, but it does increase the likelihood that Tolkien deliberately chose to build the name out of elements that recall these terms, even if they’re not the same. He did, after all, have complete control over his invention.

Comment: @chepner: FWIW, having a word like /ata/ as a term for a close family member (like father) in several completely unrelated languages is not that surprising, as it's a typical ["babble word"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mama_and_papa) easily vocalized by a baby learning to talk (and eagerly filled with meaning by the baby's parents). As a linguist, Tolkien may well have been aware of this phenomenon, or at least of the fact that such words are indeed common across many languages.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes.**

In-world: In Quenya, the name signifies *[The One (God), Allfather](https://www.elfdict.com/w/eru/eq)*.

Out-world: It should hardly come as a surprise that a unique, transcendent, relational, parental God should be called "The One" and "Father". Simply because the God of his invented world is presumed to be the same God of the real world. So, not entirely made up!

Comment: His invented world actually *is* (a past version of) our world, in-universe.

Comment: "Simply because the God of his invented world is presumed to be the same God of the real world. So, not entirely made up!" Agreed, but the title *Allfather* certainly also alludes to Odin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_names_of_Odin) of Norse mythology, which was so influential in Tolkien's languages and lore.

Comment: @LarsH It's worth noting that post-Christian writing about Norse mythology has been heavily influenced by Christianity as well.

Answer (score 2):

Out-of-world: The consonants 'R' and 'L' are nearly or completely indistinguishable in some languages and accents (e.g. Spanish, Japanese). So "Eru" is a bit like "Ellu". Now, "El" is the name of a deity, or the noun for "deity", in several semitic languages (see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_(deity))); what's more is that another variant of that deity's name is "Illu". So "Eru Iluvatar" hints very strongly at **the Judeo-Christian deity**, which - while today is considered to be the single deity - is a sort of amalgam of Yehova/Yahweh and El/Illu. These were locally popular deities in the ancient kingdoms of Judea and Israel (see that same article).

Comment: This is worth expanding with sources - I don't remember where exactly I read this, but it's likely in Christopher Tolkien's _History of Middle-earth_ if someone wants to sift through it. Helge Fauskanger might also mention it on his _Ardalambion_ site; or search up David Salo's publications.

Comment: @Rich: This was always obvious to me when reading the Silmarillion, the Encyclopedia of Arda, and wikis later on. I didn't read any deeper analysis. Ah, and I guess I should mention I'm from a Jewish family and a native Hebrew speaker...

Comment: Downvoted until you can provide evidence that Tolkien did in fact derive "Éru" from the Semitic "El", and not one of the many other sources he's documented as having used for his languages.

Comment: –1 R and L are completely distinguishable in Spanish. Perhaps you are thinking V and B?

Comment: In addition to the other real-world-language objections, ‘Elu’ means ‘King’, in one of the Moriquendian languages (can’t remember which; only know that Elu Thingol is King Thingol/Greymantle). So I’m not sure that Tolkien was going for that.

Comment: @Fivesideddice: "King" and "God" are closely related concepts. In Judaism, Yehovah's name is customarily not used directly, and one of the euphemisms, so to speak, is "The king of kings of kings" or "supreme king" (which could also be translated as "high king").

Comment: It is a mistake to say "L" and "R" are indistinguishable in e.g. Japanese. Rather, a Japanese speaker has a hard time distinguishing the *English* consonants, because both sound like the *single* Japanese consonant which has allophones similar to both. This is common with East Asian languages in general, but not so much the Hebrew, Latin, Germanic, Celtic, or Finno-Ugric ones from which Tolkien drew most of his inspiration. It may be that IL was inspired somewhat by El(ohim) (even though "All" is the more obvious source), but I think you're off target on Eru.